# How to create trigger for insert to check logical delete in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I use SQL Server 2017 and I have a table `Participants` that has 2 columns, `user_id` and `active`. `user_id` is the primary key and `active` is Boolean for logical delete.

I wrote a trigger that when you delete a row, just set `active=0` and record remains.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PDel]
ON [dbo].[Participants]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Participants
    SET active = 0
    WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM deleted)
END
```

Now I want to write a trigger that when I want to insert into table `Participants`, it should first check if that record is available. If it is available, just set `active = 1`, and if it is not, insert that record into the table.

What should I do to write such code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_InsertUsers]
ON [dbo].[Participants]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Update the existing one
    Update Participants
        Set active = 1
    where [user_id] in (select [user_id] from inserted);    


-- Insert the new ones
    INSERT INTO Participants ([user_id] , active)
    SELECT i.[user_id] , 1
    FROM inserted i 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 1 
                        FROM Participants p
                        WHERE i.[user_id] = p.[user_id]);
END
```